# Spring boot not forwarding url path to index.html React bundle

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot, ubuntu, progressive-web-apps

I deployed a **JAR** for my REST API using *Spring boot*. The app also serves the *React web app bundle* through the `/static` directory.

The problem is that when I try to enter this link:
http://SERVER-IP/password/change/1d0afe95-a643-437e-8307-ed7688b6a756

I see `Whitelabel Error Page 404` message mapped instead of the expected page.

This issue isn't happening in my local environment, just in production (Ubuntu 16 vps).

Here is the code of my **WebMvcConfig** class:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private final long MAX_AGE_SECS = 3600;

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("*")
                .allowedMethods("HEAD", "OPTIONS", "GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE")
                .maxAge(MAX_AGE_SECS);
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/{spring:\\w+}")
                .setViewName("forward:/");
        registry.addViewController("/**/{spring:\\w+}")
                .setViewName("forward:/");
        registry.addViewController("/{spring:\\w+}/**{spring:?!(\\.js|\\.css)$}")
                .setViewName("forward:/");
    }

}
```

**POM.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>XXX</groupId>
    <artifactId>XXX</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>XXX</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- For Working with Json Web Tokens (JWT) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- For Java 8 Date/Time Support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And here is the javascript code for the **routes**:

```
export const routes = (
  <Switch>
    <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Routines} />
    <PrivateRoute exact path="/home" component={Routines} />
    <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
    <Route exact path="/signup" component={Signup} />
    <PrivateRoute exact path="/password/change" component={ChangePassword} />
    <Route exact path="/password/change/:token" component={ChangePassword} />
    <Route exact path="/password/reset" component={ResetPassword} />
    <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
  </Switch>
);
```

All other routes are working fine either by React routing or by inserting the URL in the browser

How can I do to forward all routes to index.html, even in production?

Comment: can you try to remove the `exact` from `<Route exact path="/password/change/:token" component={ChangePassword} />`

Comment: Why do you think that's the issue? I will try but I can't figure out why that might be the problem @ThomasAndolf

Comment: Exact is used to match exactly one thing. it can only match `/password/change` not any input value is my guess and there you dont have any public route, so that probably slips through to the backend.

Comment: When I test it in dev environment `react-router` is mapping well the routes in both scenarios. I guess it's maybe a Spring thing, but I am not sure why it works just in dev.

Comment: caching in the browser? run incognito mode?

Comment: Tried in incognito, closing all existing tabs and it keeps showing me Whitelabel error page

Comment: well we dont know your environments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the `regex`es at `addViewControllers` method in `WebMvcConfig` class.

In particular, `\\w` was only matching *alphabets* and *numbers*, but it wasn't matching **hyphens**. For a strange reason, which may be because of browser caching, it worked in **the dev** environment.

Here is the correct `regex` : `^[a-zA-Z\d-_]` and below, the correct `addViewControllers` method:

```
@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/{spring:^[a-zA-Z\\d-_]+}")
            .setViewName("forward:/");
    registry.addViewController("/**/{spring:^[a-zA-Z\\d-_]+}")
            .setViewName("forward:/");
    registry.addViewController("/{spring:^[a-zA-Z\\d-_]+}/**{spring:?!(\\.js|\\.css)$}")
            .setViewName("forward:/");
}
```